# I'm trying to plot a heatmap based on a dataframe that is comprised of 3 lists, but all I get is this weird thing

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I built this data frame

`data = pd.DataFrame({'X': x, 'Y': y, 'Z': spikes})`

from 3 lists I've created, each 599 elements long :

```
x = list_of_xpos
y = list_of_ypos
spikes = list_of_spiking_rate
```

I'm trying to plot the spiking rate (of a neuron) against the matching x and y position. I need the spiking rate to serve as the intensity of the heatmap. 
I'm using this:

```
data_pivoted = data.pivot("X", "Y", "Z")
ax = sns.heatmap(data_pivoted)
plt.show()
```

I get two things:

1. ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
2. This bizarre plot:

[image]

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is duplicate locate data in your data, you could try

```
data.duplicated(['X', 'Y']).any()
```

if return True, then you could do a groupby of X,Y then use a unstack. consider code below:

```
data.groupby(['X', 'Y']).mean().unstack()
```

Comment: thank you, but it still brings up the same issue, duplicate entries..